# From a chrome extension how to check if a web-element present or not on page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a chrome extension that would let me check if some elements are present on the page opened. Can someone help me here. Its giving null values when I use the code below.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "A browser action with a popup that changes the page color.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "Set this page's color.",
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
if(jQuery('#nav').is(':visible')==true){
    alert("true");
}else {
        alert("false");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the "content script", which will run on the pages you specify. The popup page only gets called when user clicks your extension button.

```json
{
    ...,
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "script.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

More info here: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html

Also, when checking, firs check if the element actually exists then check it's visibility:

```js
var $nav = jQuery('#nav');

if ($nav.length > 0 && $nav.is(':visible') == true) {
    alert("true");
} else {
    alert("false");
}
```

Comment: Or they could use `chrome.tabs.executeScript` from the popup (no need to have content scripts injected all the time if you dont have to), just like they did in the sample `make page red` that he used to base that test off.

Comment: @PAEz I tried this but I am unable to use jQuery like this. I am able to use only plain vanilla javascript. Do I need to load it somehow?

Comment: @expressions Inject jquery with the executeScript and then in the callback of the executeScript inject your script..pretty sure that works (dont normally use jq myself) and to tired to test